# SQL Server Management Studio output is different from VBA Result Set

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I have a solution for taking a set of data in excel, running each row against a SQL Server table to find out if it needs to update an existing entry, insert a new SQL Server row, or do nothing; accurately entering what field(s) it updated into an audit table.  It keeps a count of actions as a variable in the SQL  string and selects that variable at the end of the 'update or insert' logic.

As a sample it looks roughly like this:

SAMPLE_TABLE:

```
+--------------------------+
| EMP_ID | NAME_A | NAME_B |
+--------------------------+
| 1234   | MARY   | BROWN  |
| 5678   | JONN   | SMITH  |
+--------------------------+
```

AUDIT_TABLE:

```
+--------------------------+
| EMP_ID | FIELD | OLD_VAL |
+--------------------------+
+--------------------------+
```

New records in Excel tbl:

```
| emp_id |  f_name   | l_name
| 1234   |  mary     | wilson
| 9012   |  adam     | smith
```

So on the first Excel row above the SQL I generated with VBA, if given line breaks, would look like this

```sql
1  SET NOCOUNT ON SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
2  DECLARE @RWCT int
3  DECLARE @EID int
4  DECLARE @NM_A nvarchar(55)
5  DECLARE @NM_B nvarchar(55)
6  DECLARE @X int
7  
8  BEGIN
9  UPDATE SAMPLE_TABLE
10  SET EMP_ID = 1234
11  WHERE EMP_ID = 1234
12  
13  IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
14  BEGIN
15  INSERT INTO SAMPLE_TABLE
16  (EMP_ID, NAME_A, NAME_B)
17  VALUES (1234, 'MARY', 'WILSON')
18  SET @RWCT = 1
19  END
20  
21  ELSE
22  BEGIN
23  SELECT @EID = EMP_ID
24  , @NM_A = NAME_A
25  , @NM_B = NAME_B
26  FROM SAMPLE_TABLE
27  WHERE EMP_ID = 1234
28  
29  SET @X = 0
30  SET @RWCT = 0
31  
32  IF 'MARY' != @NM_A
33  BEGIN
34  INSERT INTO AUDIT_TABLE
35  (EMP_ID, FIELD, OLD_VAL)
36  (@EID, 'NAME_A', @NM_A)
37  SET @X = @X + 1
38  SET @RWCT = @RWCT + 1
39  END
40  
41  IF 'WILSON' != @NM_B
42  BEGIN
43  INSERT INTO AUDIT_TABLE
44  (EMP_ID, FIELD, OLD_VAL)
45  (@EID, 'NAME_B', @NM_B)
46  SET @X = @X + 1
47  SET @RWCT = @RWCT + 1
48  END
49  
50  IF @X > 0
51  BEGIN
52  UPDATE SAMPLE_TABLE
53  SET NAME_A = 'MARY'
54  , NAME_B = 'WILSON'
55  WHERE EMP_ID = 1234
56  SET @RWCT = @RWCT + 1
57  END
58  END
59  
60  SELECT @RWCT AS CT
61  
62  END
```

Run exactly this way if I copy paste that string into MS SQL Server Management Studio 2014 the Results outputs what it should

```
+---------+
|   |  CT |
+---------+
| 1 |  2  |
+---------+
```

If I then update the row for `emp_id 1234` back to `1234 | mary | brown` so I can run this statement through VBA and output the resultset the VBA prints `0`. The values in that SQL string replaced with the ones from the 2nd Excel row output `1` from MS SQL Studio, and also `0` from VBA (so inserts count incorrectly from VBA as well).

- If I update line 60 to `SELECT 5 AS CT`:
  SQL Server Management Studio outputs 5, as does VBA
- If I update line 60 to `DECLARE @TEMP int SET @TEMP = 3 SELECT @TEMP AS CT`:
  SQL Server Management Studio outputs 3, as does VBA
- If I update line 60 to `DECLARE @TEMP int SET @TEMP = @RWCT SELECT @TEMP AS CT`:
  SQL Server Management Studio outputs 2, VBA outputs 0
- If line 60 is left alone and I update line 30 to `SET @RWCT = 10`:
  SQL Server Management Studio outputs 12, VBA outputs 10

Regardless of where I run it, the tables all get updated appropriately, the output of my action taken count is the only thing that varies.

I've rather run out of brainstorming to chase the issue down further to figure out why VBA isn't respecting the order of the SQL statements when it sends the query through.  Has anyone run across this before?

Comment: So you're saying that when this SQL command is executed from VBA (I assume with ADODB.Command?), the `insert` statements all work, but the `set`s that increment `@RWCT` don't? Can you show exactly how you execute this from VBA?

Comment: I'm intrigued. On line 53 of your code, why are you updating `SET NAME_A = 'MARY'` when it's `NAME_B` that has changed value? And then on line 56 you `SET @RWCT = @RWCT + 1234` so why doesn't this update scenario return CT = 1236? In fact, why are you expecting CT = 2 from the update - only one of the fields changed value. So shouldn't CT = 1235 in this case?

Comment: gserg - the set statements that increment @rwct work perfectly fine as well, as i said when i run the query in ms sql server mgmnt it outputs exactly what's expected.

Comment: skippy - autocomplete got the better of me when i was rewriting my logic into this example scenario & changed '1' into '1234'; also the update around ln53 updates all fields that aren't a key, i just had a tab in there, had copied it into excel to quickly append the line numbers to the strings & it didn't catch the tabbed cell.  fixed now

Comment: If you are trying to rollback your change to replicate the results, you also have to `delete SAMPLE_TABLE where Emp_ID = 1234`.

Comment: delete from sample_table where emp_id = 1234 would result in this statement returning "1" as rwct when run properly through sql, not 2.


delete where emp_id = 1234

...declare statements...

update sample_table set emp_id = 1234 where emp_id = 1234

if rowcount = 0 - - evals to true

begin

insert into sample_table (emp_id, name_a, name_b) values (1234, 'mary', 'wilson')

set rwct = 1

end

- - ...else block not evaluated ... - - 

select @rwct as ct

Answer (score 0):

Wrong coding:

- Lines 11-13 are just to check if record exists. Update hits Log file,
  the operation is much slower. You can just use clause `IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 1 FROM  SAMPLE_TABLE WHERE EMP_ID = 1234)`
- Lines from 32-59 wont execute at all because `@NM_A` and `@NM_B` are
  not set yet and equal `NULL`. As the result `IF 'MARY' != @NM_A` will
  be always false.

Comment: The update approach is much better for ensuring concurrent access does not result in duplicates. `IF EXISTS` can return `true` to both concurrent processes, `update` will place a lock. I'm not saying it's the right way though. A `merge` or a `select (with updlock)` would be better.

Comment: lines 24 & 25 were setting those variables but somehow got blanked out when I pasted it over into my question.  updated now

Comment: GSerg , in this case `update` will not place a lock until the end of procedure.  And I do not it is necessary in case of reporting to Excel.

Comment: aeris311 Logic still does not seem to be right. `@RWCT` can return 1,1235 and 1236. It is too complicated for such a small portion of code.

Comment: I had scaled down & replaced the actual field/table names my logic was written for, in doing so autocomplete turned my increment statement into the variable plus the emp_id value i had typed a couple times

Comment: So, try to get right logic in the small scale, and then you might be able to scale it up.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting `SET NOCOUNT ON` to `SET NOCOUNT OFF`.  Possibly it's affecting `@RWCT` in VBA but not in SQL Server.

Comment: `NOCOUNT` does not affect `@RWCT`, but it can affect number of recordsets VBA receives. This can mess up consuming results on the VBA side, but `SET NOCOUNT ON` is the way to disable it. `SET NOCOUNT OFF` [enables](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080624-00/?p=21863/#8647383) the noise being sent.

Comment: when I didn't set nocount on vba wouldn't even work with the resultset object

Comment: @aeris311 How many recordsets does VBA receive anyway? Can you call `NextRecordset` several times?